# Problems with html2canvas and justgage

Tags: javascript, chart.js, html2canvas, justgage

I'm facing a problem with `html2canvas` and `justgage`. The `html2canvas` edits and cuts the **original image**, making it impossible to see the informations.

Here is the pictures of canvas

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIFWg.png) and
[edited by html2canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nHRz.png)

.. and the code of html2canvas:

```
function screenshot(){ //function to get a picture 
          html2canvas(document.getElementById('gauges')).then(function(canvas){
          onRendered:
            locale = canvas.toDataURL() // here i keep the image base64 in a variable
        })
      }
```

(Sorry I'm Brazilian and I'm using `Google Translate`)

Comment: Is your canvas large enough?

Comment: Is responsive according to the screen size

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put up a snippet which shows the problem as I can't tell whether it's just that the canvas is too small (in which case things will just get cropped) or whether there's something deeper going on. Thanks.

Comment: here i have two cases of printing on the screen with html2canvas, in first i just printed the body of html, and another is a print of a one div
[the images](https://imgur.com/a/epfUs8L?third_party=1#_=_)